# Separate string to colum by delimiter without text to column wizard

Tags: excel

How can you separate a string into separate columns delimited by quotes (`""`) without using the text to column feature... as in

```
A1={"WATERBOTTLES","HOWMANY":"8","HOWMUCHDOTHEYCOST":"1"}

B1=WATERBOTTLES, HOWMANY : 8, HOWMUCH DOTHEYCOST : 1
```

Comment: If you're just removing the quotes you can use `SUBSTITUTE()`

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the string "," into tab(\t) in Textpad. and copy paste the value in excel.

- Replace the beginning double quote, as like replace ^" with empty string
- Replace the last double quote, as like replace "\n with just \n

(Let me know, if you want screen shot, i can add it)

Each value will appear in different column.