# Seperate a string into columns excel with out 'text to columns"

Tags: json, excel

I do a json query and it puts all this data into a single cell

```
{"waterbottle","last_qty":"8","last_price":"1.0"}
```

With out using text to columns, I want to take everything surrounded in quotes and put it in a new column that refreshes when ever the original cell updates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Separate string to colum by delimiter without text to column wizard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861219/separate-string-to-colum-by-delimiter-without-text-to-column-wizard)

Answer (score 0):

If your query always returns the same number of elements, you can use a combination of FIND and MID formulae to extract the various elements.